# Preserve opened webpack sourcemaps in chrome developer tools page after refresh

Tags: webpack, google-developer-tools

I would like to preserve the opened structure in the 'Page' tab inside developer tools after the page refresh, so I don't have to open them again and again because I get dizzy.

**Example gif:**

[image]